# how to search query using SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Scenario:

I have a table which is named 'contacts' and I have 15 rows in it for the data. The first 3 rows will be loaded and be visible in the page because I limit it to 3. For example, the value of the data were:

```
 ---------------
|     name      |
|---------------|
| Peter         |
| James         |
| John          |
 ---------------
```

I search for the name that starts with letter 'J' using LIKE operator and there are also data that has not been loaded AND ALSO STARTS WITH LETTER 'J'.

How can I search for the names of the FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY (LIMIT) that starts with letter 'J' and prevent from retrieving of the remaining rows that has not been loaded in sql?

```
public function search(){

    $query = "SELECT * 
                FROM contacts 
                WHERE user_id=? 
                AND     name LIKE '%".$this->key."%' 
                    OR  company LIKE '%".$this->key."%' 
                    OR email LIKE '%".$this->key."%' 
                    OR phone LIKE '%".$this->key."%' 
                ORDER BY id DESC 
                LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0";

    $this->conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO:: ERRMODE_WARNING);
    $select = $this->conn->prepare($query);

    $select->bindParam(1, $this->user_id);

    $select->execute();

    return $select;
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a problem with database design rather than a MySQL query. You shouldnt be storing everything in one table and only looking at the first three rows...

Comment: Unclear... the shown code is not relative to previous explaination.

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Comment: Is that the sample data or the expected result? This question is quite unclear.

Comment: That query would need some brackets OR < Hint it wont do what you expect

Comment: That is my sql but I still retrieving the data that has not been loaded to the page. My goal is to SEARCH/FILTER DATA of the loaded data and prevent from GETTING DATA THAT EXCEED TO THE LIMIT. @Akina

Comment: `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` makes little sense. RDBMS tables do not have inherent row ordering.

Comment: @Ice76 this is not a database design problem for I am only using one table and use its field name for searching/filtering. More just like use a subquery  that first gets  TOP 3 ROWS and perform LIKE OPERATOR

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name
FROM (SELECT name
      FROM contacts
      ORDER BY (unknown criteria)
      LIMIT 3) subquery
WHERE name LIKE `J%`
```

Applying the same to the query shown in the question code:

```
SELECT *
FROM (  SELECT * 
        FROM contacts 
        WHERE user_id=? 
        AND (   name LIKE '%".$this->key."%' 
             OR company LIKE '%".$this->key."%' 
             OR email LIKE '%".$this->key."%' 
             OR phone LIKE '%".$this->key."%' )
        ORDER BY id DESC 
        LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0  ) subquery
WHERE name LIKE 'J%'
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: To add some detail/explanation: This solution takes your original query that returns the 3 rows, and uses it as a subquery to create a `derived table`. This allows you to query the result set from of your original table. Another option that you commonly see across other RDBMSes (with the same effect) would be to use a `common table expression` instead of a derived table.

Comment: @RToyo this is what I mean. I am really new in subquerying and sorry for my grammar. Let me try this for a bit